# Gaussian Blur UI elements

Tags: unity, compiz, themes, gui

Is there a way that I can use Ubuntu already existing Gaussian Blur code and apply it to other UI elements?

You can clearly see it being used in the top **panel**:

[image]

And on the **Dash**:

[image]

So, I **know** the code already exists to do it, and it is (most likely) possible, but why hasn't anyone used it in other UI elements like the **[launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498503/unity-gaussian-blur-to-the-launcher-bar)**?

There are some elements that are translucent for whatever reason like when choosing to upload a file:

[image]

But it doesn't use the Gaussian blur. And frankly doesn't look good without the blurring. So how can I fix this?

Comment: Version tags are to be used when the problem is specific to a version. Neither Gaussian blur nor Unity dash nor the other apps not using it are specific to 16.04.

Comment: It may be using code from the <a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/18413/what-is-nux-and-whats-it-used-for">Nux Toolkit</a> which Unity uses.